# Scala: "Genericising" over singleton types?

Tags: scala, types, type-level-computation, singleton-type

In Scala values and objects have singleton types assigned to them individually. So we can have:

```
val x = 1
type X = x.type
val y = 2
type Y = y.type
```

- Can I write a method that takes only x as its argument?

I tried:

```
val x = 1
def foo(i: x.type ) = println(x.toString)
```

but it is giving me an error. I think it's complaining the about the fact that the type is unknown. Is there a way of specifying the fact that `i` is expected to be an int so that we can use say `.tofloat` on it?

- Do `X` and `Y` above, namely the singleton types of `1` & `2`, have a common ancestor so I can write a generic code that involves the singleton type of say `Int` values.
- Similarly,

if I had for example

```
 val list = [1,2,3]
```

is there a way of writing a code that genericises over these and can only be fed one of these values?

Comment: for me, `x.type` where x is an Int doesn't work. It works if `x` is an `AnyRef` such as `List`

Comment: I find your comment very vague. Could you make it a bit more specific please.

Comment: you're first code paragraph (`val x = 1; type X = x.type` etc...)  doesn't compile.  `found   : x.type (with underlying type Int)`
`required: AnyRef`

Comment: Yep, only objects have singleton type. For values you will have to wait for literal types in one of the upcoming Scala releases.

Comment: oh that explains it! :)

Comment: @slouc Out of curiosity, do you know what the answer to the questions will be in Dotty?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, to be honest. Do you want to restrict your method parameter to literal type "1"? That will be possible. See [proposal](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html).

Comment: @slouc here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762710/scala-making-connections-between-types-and-values this gives you a better picture what I am trying to do! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.12.5, it works for boxed non-primitive integers only:

```
val x: java.lang.Integer = 42
def foo(i: x.type): Unit = println(i.toFloat)
```

I don't know why it doesn't work for `val x: Int` though. In Dotty, it works also for primitive types:

```
val x: Int = 42
def foo(i: x.type): Unit = println(x.toFloat)
```

For more than one value (list), you could take an enumeration, or simply create a little class with a private constructor, and instantiate all valid values inside the companion class:

```
class SmallInt private(value: Int) {
  def asFloat = value.toFloat
}

object SmallInt {
  val one = new SmallInt(1)
  val two = new SmallInt(2)
  val three = new SmallInt(3)
}
```

this wouldn't compile then:

```
val foo = new SmallInt(345678) // forbidden
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762710/scala-making-connections-between-types-and-values which was the reason I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

> I write a method that takes only x as its argument?

If it can only take one parameter, then it doesn't need to

```
val x = 1
def f() = println(x.toString)
```

> Do X and Y above, namely the singleton types of 1 & 2, have a common ancestor so I can write a generic code that involves the singleton type of say Int values...

I don't understand. One way to have a function takes a set of arbitrary classes as input is to use implicit conversion

```
trait CanUse{
    def use(): Int
}

def f[A](a: A)(implicit cvt: (A) => CanUse): Int = cvt(a).use() + 1
```

then define implicit converter for each of the acceptable input type

```
implicit class UsableInt(i: Int) extends CanUse{
   def use() = i
}
```

Comment: thanks! re: `def f() = ...` duh! :D this is a minimal example of course. what I wanted to do is something like: `trait X{private val i: int; def foo(j: i.type) } so that `foo` can only be called with the right value.

Comment: I think you should define better why you want foo to be callable only with a specific value. If it is just to get the value, then no need to pass it, as I said. If you have other reason (I cannot guess one), you probably should choose another design

Comment: Here is the use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762710/scala-making-connections-between-types-and-values

Answer (score 0):

Scala 2.13 solves that issue :D

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/T637W491Sl2gN50ZVWAvBQ

```scala
val x = 1
type X = x.type
val y = 2
type Y = y.type
```

Comment: @SethTisue Fixed.