# Scala: Type-level programming parameterised by nested type value

Tags: scala, type-constraints, type-level-computation

Currently I have a piece of program that implements peano arithmetic:

```
sealed trait NaturalNumber
```

and a function called `getResource` that picks up natural number type-value in its arguments which have the interface:

```
sealed trait VersionNumber {
  type Nat <: NaturalNumber
}
```

and checks the values against a reference type-value version numbers: `MAJ` and `MIN`, provided in this interface:

```
trait ResourceManifest {
  def getResource: Int
  type Major <: NaturalNumber
  type Minor <: NaturalNumber
}
```

depending on which, the function does or does not compile. The function has this form:

```
    def getResource(manifest: ResourceManifest)(maj: VersionNumber, min: VersionNumber)
               (implicit
                maj_check: manifest.Major IsEqual maj.Nat,
                min_check: manifest.Minor IsLessOrEqual min.Nat
) = manifest.getResource
```

Here is the [full code](https://gist.github.com/ShahOdin/428c64b91984c2d55160a98e53fa40a5/9cba74308afcebb596f9f9241e92cb8945e6e59b). (Here is an alternative [implementation](https://gist.github.com/ShahOdin/37cd6f72d39b29da5366201a3f32ecec) if you like type-recursion.)

As it is, this is powered by overriding type values which the average Scala user might not be too comfortable with. Also, `getResource` gets separate arguments for the major and minor versions.

Ideally I would like to user to provide values instead of types say in a wrapper class:

```
case class VersionInfo(major: VersionNumber, minor: VersionNumber)
```

so that my manifest is of this form:

```
trait ResourceManifestRefactored {
  def getResource: Int
  val versionInfo: VersionInfo
}
```

and similarly have:

```
def getResourceRefactored(manifest: ResourceManifestRefactored)(versionInfo: VersionInfo)
```

and do my type level constraints by picking up the version-types from the wrapper version value class: `VersionInfo`. However I am struggling to get it to work despite me doing it in many different ways. for instance I tried using doing my type checks directly with path-dependent types but that failed. I also tried defining `MAJ` and `MIN` based on the types in inside `VersionInfo` but the type constraints are no longer working the way they are expected to. I understand we are potentially facing the similar problems that are solved by the likes of [aux-pattern](http://gigiigig.github.io/posts/2015/09/13/aux-pattern.html) but I am struggling to fit a similar solution to my problem.

Essentially, I want to have pre-defined objects wrapping types and I want to do type constraints through these objects instead of the types directly.

**Is there a fundumental reason why I can't and if not, how can I do it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that `__1` and `__2` are two objects that extend `VersionNumber`, with two different types `_1, _2` that extend `Nat` inside them. Is there any reason why the compiler would reject to compile

```
val foo: VersionInfo = VersionInfo( if (math.random < 0.5) __1 else __2, __2)
```

? In your current code, there is no reason why the compiler would reject this. This means that your `VersionInfo` breaks the constant paths between the outer constants `__1`, `__2` and the inner values `major` and `minor`, which are stored inside of your `VersionInfo`. For example, as soon as you pass `__1` as `major` to `VersionInfo` `foo`, the information that `__1.Nat` is the same type as `foo.major.Nat` is lost forever.

This can be easily solved by simply not throwing this type information away, but instead attaching it as type parameters to `VersionInfo`.

Assuming that your natural numbers looks somewhat like this:

```
sealed trait NaturalNumber
class _3 extends NaturalNumber
class _2 extends _3
class _1 extends _2
class _0 extends _1

class VersionNumber {
  type Nat <: NaturalNumber
}

val __0 = new VersionNumber { type Nat = _0 }
val __1 = new VersionNumber { type Nat = _1 }
val __2 = new VersionNumber { type Nat = _2 }
val __3 = new VersionNumber { type Nat = _3 }

type IsEqual[A, B] = A =:= B
type IsLessOrEqual[A, B] = A <:< B
```

you can define `VersionInfo` and `ResourceManifest` as follows:

```
case class VersionInfo[Major, Minor](
  major: VersionNumber { type Nat = Major },
  minor: VersionNumber { type Nat = Minor }
)

trait ResourceManifest {
  def getResource: Int
  type Major <: NaturalNumber
  type Minor <: NaturalNumber
}
```

and then use them as argument types of `getResource`:

```
def getResource[A, B]
  (manifest: ResourceManifest)
  (versionInfo: VersionInfo[A, B])
  (implicit
    maj_check: manifest.Major IsEqual A,
    min_check: manifest.Minor IsLessOrEqual B
  )
: Unit = println("it compiles, ship it")
```

A little test:

```
val manifest21 = new ResourceManifest {
  def getResource = 21
  type Major = _2
  type Minor = _1
}

val manifest22 = new ResourceManifest {
  def getResource = 22
  type Major = _2
  type Minor = _2
}

getResource(manifest21)(VersionInfo(__2, __1))
getResource(manifest21)(VersionInfo(__2, __2))
// getResource(manifest22)(VersionInfo(__2, __1)) // won't compile, good
getResource(manifest22)(VersionInfo(__2, __2))
```

In the code above, I've tried to use the same names [as in this answer of yours from few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50783958/2707792).

Comment: Excellent. great explanation. I was taking a bite that was too big to chew as I wanted to do two things at once. You have beautifully solved the client side of it. I wonder if the manifest side can also be solved as well. As I said, Ideally I would like the version information in the manifest to be provided through values, not types. I tried experimenting with circular type definitions (ie defining at the base trait: `type Minor = versionInfo.minor.Nat;  val versionInfo: VersionInfo[Major,Minor] ` or using `VersionInfo[_._]` but I didn't get far. Is there any way of getting that to work?

Comment: @Mathsnoob Not sure what you're asking in the follow-up question - it seems that you can treat `ResourceManifest` in exactly the same way as `VersionInfo`. I've added an alternative solution that omits all generic type parameters and treats manifests and infos symmetrically. Won't change this answer, because it functions just fine in the sense that I originally understood.

Answer (score 1):

Similar, but slightly different alternative solution that does not use any type parameters on `VersionInfo` or `ResourceManifest`, and instead relies on `Aux`-typedefs.

Allows to instantiate both `VersionInfo`s and `ResourceManifest`s from `VersionNumber` objects, without using any explicit type parameters anywhere.

Here's the whole thing as a single wall of code:

```
sealed trait NaturalNumber
class _3 extends NaturalNumber
class _2 extends _3
class _1 extends _2
class _0 extends _1

abstract class VersionNumber {
  type Nat <: NaturalNumber
  def toInt: Int
}

val __0 = new VersionNumber { type Nat = _0 ; def toInt = 0 }
val __1 = new VersionNumber { type Nat = _1 ; def toInt = 1 }
val __2 = new VersionNumber { type Nat = _2 ; def toInt = 2 }
val __3 = new VersionNumber { type Nat = _3 ; def toInt = 3 }

object VersionNumber {
  type Aux[N <: NaturalNumber] = VersionNumber {
    type Nat = N
  }
}

type IsEqual[A, B] = A =:= B
type IsLessOrEqual[A, B] = A <:< B

abstract class VersionInfo {
  type Major <: NaturalNumber
  type Minor <: NaturalNumber
  val major: VersionNumber.Aux[Major]
  val minor: VersionNumber.Aux[Minor]
}

object VersionInfo {
  type Aux[A <: NaturalNumber, B <: NaturalNumber] = VersionInfo {
    type Major = A
    type Minor = B
  }
  def apply[A <: NaturalNumber, B <: NaturalNumber](
    a: VersionNumber { type Nat = A },
    b: VersionNumber { type Nat = B }
  ): VersionInfo.Aux[A, B] = new VersionInfo {
    type Major = A
    type Minor = B
    val major = a
    val minor = b
  }
}

abstract class ResourceManifest {

  type Major <: NaturalNumber
  type Minor <: NaturalNumber
  val major: VersionNumber.Aux[Major] 
  val minor: VersionNumber.Aux[Minor]

  def getResource: Int = major.toInt * 10 + minor.toInt
}

object ResourceManifest {
  type Aux[A <: NaturalNumber, B <: NaturalNumber] = ResourceManifest {
    type Major = A
    type Minor = B
  }
  def apply[A <: NaturalNumber, B <: NaturalNumber](
    a: VersionNumber { type Nat = A },
    b: VersionNumber { type Nat = B }
  ): ResourceManifest.Aux[A, B] = new ResourceManifest {
    type Major = A
    type Minor = B
    val major = a
    val minor = b
  }
}

def getResource[
  MnfMaj <: NaturalNumber, 
  MnfMin <: NaturalNumber, 
  VrsMaj <: NaturalNumber, 
  VrsMin <: NaturalNumber
]
  (manifest: ResourceManifest.Aux[MnfMaj, MnfMin])
  (versionInfo: VersionInfo.Aux[VrsMaj, VrsMin])
  (implicit
    maj_check: MnfMaj IsEqual VrsMaj,
    min_check: MnfMin IsLessOrEqual VrsMin
  )
: Unit = println("it compiles, ship it")



val manifest21 = ResourceManifest(__2, __1)
val manifest22 = ResourceManifest(__2, __2)

getResource(manifest21)(VersionInfo(__2, __1))
getResource(manifest21)(VersionInfo(__2, __2))
// getResource(manifest22)(VersionInfo(__2, __1)) // still won't compile, good
getResource(manifest22)(VersionInfo(__2, __2))
```